# Mina - Foreman - Bundle Command Not Found Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, foreman, mina

I'm using ruby 2.1.5 mri, and mina (0.3.1). rbenv 0.4.0-129-g7e0e85b, and rbenvsudo plugin.
But cannot deployed properly,  foreman cannot initalize bundler. What is the problem in here?

Here is the mina verbose output;

#### Mina trace output

```
-----> Exporting foreman procfile for app
$ cd /home/deployer/app/current ; sudo bundle exec foreman export upstart /etc/init -a app -u     deployer -d /home/deployer/app/current -l /home/deployer/app/shared/log
bash: line 168: cd: /home/deployer/app/current: No such file or directory
sudo: bundle: command not found
! ERROR: Deploy failed.
-----> Cleaning up build
$ rm -rf "$build_path"
Unlinking current
$ rm -f "deploy.lock"
OK
```

#### /etc/sudoers

root     ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
deployer ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

#### ~/.bashrc

export PATH="$home/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=~/.rbenv/shims:~/.rbenv/bin:"$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export RAILS_ENV=production

#### /root/.bashrc

Same as ~/.bashrc